# PHPMailer - sending image in html

Tags: phpmailer

I want to send HTML email with image using PHPMailer (not attachement, but just image which would be in an email content, using link to the image). When I am sending HTML message, in most mailboxes text is visible, but image not (user has to click button "Show images" etc., and then my image appears). Can anyone help?

My code:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = "mymail@domain.com";
$mail->FromName = "mymail";
$mail->AddReplyTo("mymail@domain.com", "mymail");  
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";            
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";     
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
$mail->Username = "xxx";    
$mail->Password = "yyy";
$mail->Port = 25;               
$mail->Subject = "Subject";     
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = $message;       
$mail->AddAddress ($enduser, $enduser_name);                
$mail->Send();
```

$message is HTML code with img src="http://domain.com/logo.png"/

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You've based your code on an old example, and you're probably using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Otherwise, what @Thi Tran said is correct. You may find that using an embedded image works where linked images do not, but either way it's highly dependent on the recipient's settings, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't issue of PHPMailer. 
If someone who receive your email and they are using Outlook, Outlook will block showing image because of security.
If they are using gmail, it works fine.